# Jupyter packages

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, jupyter

I am trying to import certain packages as I am working with Jupyter notebook files, and most of the packages seem to be missing, even though I have installed them. For example, when I do the command: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` or `import requests`
I get the error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'` for the first one and a similar one for importing requests as well. I have tried `pip install requests` and `pip install bs4`, but same issue persists. I have installed them on:
"`(base) aminnazemzadeh@amins-MacBook-Pro ~ %` " which seems to be my home directory, and I also have anaconda3 installed alongside python3. What is the issue that I cannot import these modules.

I am using visual studio if it makes any difference

Once I add :

```
!pip install requests
!pip install bs4
```

I get:

```
/Users/aminnazemzadeh/.zshenv:.:1: no such file or directory: /Users/aminnazemzadeh/.cargo/env
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Users/aminnazemzadeh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in /Users/aminnazemzadeh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /Users/aminnazemzadeh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests) (1.26.11)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Users/aminnazemzadeh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Users/aminnazemzadeh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests) (2022.9.24)
/Users/aminnazemzadeh/.zshenv:.:1: no such file or directory: /Users/aminnazemzadeh/.cargo/env
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /Users/aminnazemzadeh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /Users/aminnazemzadeh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from bs4) (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /Users/aminnazemzadeh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (2.3.1)
```

followed by this warning:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 4
      2 get_ipython().system('pip install bs4')
      3 from urllib.request import urlopen
----> 4 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Thanks

Comment: can you try to use jupyter via the browser (start the server on terminal `jupyter lab`) and see if you have the packages there? i've never used jupyter on vs code

Comment: What pip version are you running? Does pip3 install work?

Comment: make sure you selecting the correct environment where you install those packages.
run jupyter notebook from conda prompt after activate the environment and if there is enviroment use pip3 to install the package and it will work

Comment: try to restart the kernel. and also the error `/Users/aminnazemzadeh/.zshenv:.:1: no such file or directory: /Users/aminnazemzadeh/.cargo/env` probably suggests that there might be an issue with your shell configuration file, which is causing the error to be displayed when you install packages using pip.

Comment: On Jupyter lab it seems to work. I do have pip3 installed as well. For the last comment, can you please explain in more details on how to run notebook from condo prompt and how to activate the environment?

Comment: @Amin , For a better future experience you should be using the magic versions of `pip install` (or `conda install` if your main package manager happens to be Anaconda/conda/mamba, which it doesn't seem to be at this time) when you are trying to run an installation from inside a `.ipynb` file. The magic commands were added a few years ago to insure installation occurs in the same environment backing the kernel that is underlying your current notebook. Read more about them [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). ...

Comment: <continued> And since that is the current best practice, always take anything you see suggesting an exclamation point in conjunction with `pip` or `conda` as perhaps being outdated advice and take it with some caution.  For the reason why the exclamation point can be deficient in handling installs from inside a running `.ipynb` file, see the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez). (Note that because of [here](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/) , `install bs4` may work being explicit is always better.)

Comment: <continued> You don't have the correct syntax for installing beautiful soup. If you search 'pip install beautifulsoup' on the web, one of the top hits you should get should lead you to https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/ . Use the command the Python Package Index (PyPI) tells you to use: `%pip install beautifulsoup4`. Sometimes you'll think you installed something and it won't work if you aren't careful, and so it is always best to check with the proper sources. Clicking on the 'Homepage' under Project Links at https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/ goes to the BeautifulSoup page.

Comment: Plus, in the future please write post titles that are specific to your question. One way to go about that is to imagine trying to recognize the post that addresses your current issue from a list of post titles. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that includes a section 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem'.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you, will do! The %pip install requests
%pip install bs4 commands fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you're installing the packages on an environment other than the one vs code is using. you can try installing the packages directly from your jupyter notebook by running the following code in a notebook cell. the current best practice to be running installs in the notebook is using the magic commands `%pip` or `%conda`:

```py
%pip install requests beautifulsoup4

# or

%conda install requests beautifulsoup4
```

this should install the packages in the same environment that the notebook is running on.

note that you may need to restart the kernel to use the affected packages.

sources:

- [Jupyter Discourse Forum - Location of libraries or extensions installed in JupyterLab](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2)
- [Jupyter Discourse Forum - Why users can install modules from pip but not from conda?](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4)
- [Installing Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-beautiful-soup)

ps: thanks [@wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8508004/wayne) for the comments regarding the current best practices for installing on the current running environment.

Comment: I am updating the question with the new error I get now

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using conda, you should install via conda whenever possible. When you install via pip, conda loses some of its ability to manage dependency versions.
2. Try creating a new conda environment, install the needed packages via conda, then set the kernel to your new environment in vscode. Dedicate conda environments to specific projects. It is okay to have a default/generic environment for playing around but not for any significant work as you can easily create errors in your other work if a dependency changes to an incompatible version.

Conda cheet sheet for reference if you need it: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf

You will need the Jupyter extension in vscode if you do not already have it installed.

You will also need to install the corresponding jupyter package in your conda environment.